# Can python (numpy) handle matrix multiplication of size 150,000x50 * 50x850,000?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

Let A be a matrix of size 150,000x50, and B of size 850,000x50. I'd like to perform the multiplication A*B.T, and I thought that numpy will not have problems handling such scale (even if it will take a few minutes). However the operation fails after ~30 minutes. I'm running on a strong machine - GCP 16 vCPUs, 64GB RAM.

Does anyone have experience performing matmul of such scale? Is there a workaround to make it work? Some library that offers parallelization?

Comment: A 150000*850000 matrix composed of 8 bytes variables, will take 1020 GB of memory. Why do you need such a big matrix ? We need more informations.

Comment: @obchardon for computing similarities. Since memory is the problem, I can breakdown the smaller matrix to chunks and run it in a loop to get the result I need. Luckily, a 10,000 * 850,000 matmul operation works. Thanks for helping me figure out the problem

Comment: Are the input/output matrices assumed to contain a lot of zeros?